# How are you supposed to pronounce the name "Hiero" from "Hiero's Journey"?

Tags: pronunciation, hieros-journey

As a non-native English speaker I've often wondered how you are supposed to pronounce "Hiero", the main character from the eponymous *Hiero's Journey* by Sterling Lanier: to my unlearned ear "HEE-ro" (just like "hero") sounds fine but it occurred to me that the name could also be spoken as "HI-ro" (like "hieroglyph", for example), so I'm uncertain which one is the correct pronunciation.

Could you help me solve this doubt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### "Hee-eh-ro" (probably).

The Appendix N book club added Hiero's Journey to their list of [must-read authors in 2017](https://appendixnbookclub.com/2017/11/13/episode-14-sterling-e-laniers-hieros-journey/). As part of their research they evidently spoke to several of Lanier's publishers to glean stories and info about his biography. This footnote is found at the end of the article.

> ***Incidentally, Lanier insisted that Hiero is pronounced “Hee-eh-ro” and not “Hero” or “Hyro”, but he was also tweaking his final publisher Donald M. Grant at the time.***

Comment: That's the way I always assumed it was pronounced. My assumption was that Lanier must have had his own good reasons for sticking in two vowels right after the H, and the most logical explanation was that he wanted each letter to represent a different sound in the finished product.

Comment: My tendency to pronounce unknown words that *look* Japanese like they *are* Japanese pays off once again

Comment: Too bad Lanier didn't spell it that way.

Comment: @elemtilas Which way?

Comment: @Kevin Although Hiroaki (shortened to Hiro) Protagonist has to be pronounced the Japanese way in order for the joke to work.